# Can someone definitively describe the difference between the sculpt flatten, polish, and smooth brushes?

Tags: sculpting, documentation

Documentation for the sculpt brushes seems to be a bit spare.  In particular, I'm having trouble properly understanding the difference between flatten, polish, and smooth.

Also, hitting Shift seems to cause one of those to take effect when other brush types are selected.  This is convenient but I'm not sure I'm always getting consistent results.

It would be nice to have all brush types and options properly described somewhere.  I'm starting to learn the code base but I'm not far enough to really tell what the brushes actually do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Flatten** tries to make all vertices align on one plane, **smooth** tries to align vertices to the average mesh surface, and **polish** is basically a mixture of the two. This is what I have observed from use and gathered from the Wiki. When pressing `Shift` while using the *Brush* tool, you switch from *Add* to *Subtract* mode, and the opposite as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Flatten** tries to make all vertices align on one plane:
[image]

**Smooth** tries to align vertices to the average mesh surface:
[image]

**Polish** is basically a mixture of the two:
[image]

This is what I have observed from use and gathered from the Wiki.

When pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> while using the *Brush* tool, you switch to *Smooth* mode, and while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> you switch from *Add* to *Subtract* mode, and the opposite as well.

Comment: Actually, at least on a Mac, it is Ctrl that seems to reverse the sense of Add and Subtract.  Shift seems to switch to smooth but with some of the settings of the current brush.  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting! I'm using Windows 7, so it might be different.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise That's peculiar, I use Windows 8.1 pro and used to use 7 HP, and I have always used Ctrl to switch add/subtract.

Comment: I updated the answer. I think I might have changed some of my settings, not sure. The default settings act as you said.

Comment: Ctrl switches the add / subtract mode to whatever it's *not* currently set to. If you have *subtract* selected in the tool shelf, then Ctrl will use *add*. If you have *Add* selected in the tool shelf, then Ctrl will use *subtract*.

Comment: That is what I said . . .

Comment: This reads like an Abbot and Costello routine.